# Task Tracker Tutorial TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'projectRealm.write')

Tags: javascript, ios, exception, typeerror, mongodb-realm

I've followed the Task Tracker tutorial for MongoDB Realm.  The app is loading on an ios emulator.  After sign in I navigate to the MyProject's Tasks page.  I click on the + sign. The create a new task button pops up.  I type in the New Task Name and click the Create Button.  It does not create a new task.  Instead I receive the following error on the emulator - Exception  null is not an object(evaluation "projectRealm.write'). Further it shows a snippet from the code on TasksProvider.js however it is the exact code from the tutorial AND I can't see anything wrong with it.

Here is the code in question from my IDE:(the error on the emulator points to this line

projectRealm.write(() => {

Here is the larger code snippet:

```
const createTask = (newTaskName) => {
    const projectRealm = realmRef.current;
    projectRealm.write(() => {
      // Create a new task in the same partition -- that is, in the same project.
      projectRealm.create(
        "Task",
        new Task({
          name: newTaskName || "New Task",
          partition: projectPartition,
        })
      );
    });
    
  };
```

My terminal looks like this:

[Thu Mar 18 2021 11:43:04.126]  BUNDLE  ./index.js

[Thu Mar 18 2021 11:43:53.819]  LOG      Running "rn" with {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}

[Thu Mar 18 2021 11:51:29.277]  ERROR    TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'projectRealm.write')

Please help if you can. I'm new to coding and I've been stuck on this for days. I've searched SO and Git, etc.
Thanks for reading this!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the tutorial could be a bit clear.

I was getting the same error because I've created a realm app and set the appId pointing to that app in the getRealmApp.js, but that realm app didn't have the backend configuration, so every action in the app ended up on error.

In the project's README.md I found a link mentioning a "[Set up the backend for the tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/realm-app/)" so I followed that tutorial and changed the original appId for the appId asociated to the backend app and everything becomes to work.